How to convert Compiled Instructions to RawTransaction
This is what i get in versioned Transaction:
"compiledInstructions":[{"programIdIndex":4,"accountKeyIndexes":[],"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[2,80,40,1,0]}},{"programIdIndex":4,"accountKeyIndexes":[],"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[3,152,58,0,0,0,0,0,0]}},{"programIdIndex":5,"accountKeyIndexes":[0,1,0,6,7,8],"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[]}},{"programIdIndex":9,"accountKeyIndexes":[0,10,11,2,12,3,0,1,6,5,7,8],"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[62,198,214,193,213,159,108,210]}}],"addressTableLookups":[]}}
I want to decode this and extract the Raw Instructions. How do i do this

I believe there is no simple way to decode the compiled transaction.
The compiled transaction consists of the raw byte data without any other context on its meaning. It's the format you can download and get parsed from any on-chain processed transaction.
I would recommend to read the technical details on how the transaction is built:

https://medium.com/@asmiller1989/solana-transactions-in-depth-1f7f7fe06ac2
https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#rpc-changes

If you have the IDL for the program then the transaction could be decoded with use of it otherwise I expect some manual interpretation of particular bytes will be needed.
You can check discussions here

how to decode data instructions with javascript

Or for general purposes, I used the last.fm explorer-kit that I believe is nice
https://github.com/solana-fm/explorer-kit
